# Charachter identification JavaScript with Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I have long string containing the parameter name.
e.g. " The max travel distance **MAX_TRVL_DIST** is 4 meter."

I want to extract the **MAX_TRVL_DIST** from the string can anyone please help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var s =  "The max travel distance MAX_TRVL_DIST is 4 meter.";
 s.split(' ').forEach(function(str){

     if (str.indexOf('_') > -1) {
       console.log(str);
      }

    });
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Regex to find the sentence and then simply replace unwanted padding:

```js
//Load string
var str = 'The max travel distance MAX_TRVL_DIST is 4 meter';
//Find matches
var matches = str.match(/(MAX_TRVL_DIST is \w*)/ig, '');
//If have matches
if (matches.length > 0) {
  //Find match value
  var value = matches[0].replace('MAX_TRVL_DIST is ', '');
  //Log the value of "MAX_TRVL_DIST"
  console.log(value);
}
```